# Reading multiple parts of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm building a Windows app using a XML file with a lot of nesting in it - like this.

I need to access an attribute as I go down the nodes. I need to keep doing this for every "route" object available (Which may have multiple destinations and trips).

So my end Trip Object will have:

```
RouteNo = O
Destination = Queenspark
ETA = 28
```

The XML file:

```
<JPRoutePositionET xsi:schemaLocation="urn:connexionz-co-nz:jp JourneyPlanner.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:connexionz-co-nz:jp">
    <Content MaxArrivalScope="60" Expires="2015-06-14T20:21:01+12:00"/>
    <Platform Name="Manchester St & Gloucester St" PlatformTag="3330">
        <Route Name="Orange Line" RouteNo="O">
            <Destination Name="Queenspark">
                <Trip WheelchairAccess="true" TripNo="5497" ETA="28"/>
                <Trip WheelchairAccess="true" TripNo="5498" ETA="59"/>
            </Destination>
        </Route>
    </Platform>
</JPRoutePositionET>
```

My C# Code:

```
{   
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
    string StopName = loadedData.Root.Element("Platform").Attribute("Name").Value.ToString();

    var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Route")
               select new Trip
               {
                   RouteNo = (string)query.Attribute("RouteNo").Value ?? "test",
                   Destination = (string)query.Descendants("Destination").First().Attribute("Name").Value ?? "test",
                   Eta = (string)query.Element("Trip").Attribute("ETA").Value ?? "5"
               };

    List<Trip> trip = new List<Trip>();
    foreach(var a in data)
    {
        trip.Add(a);
    }

    var dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
    try
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
             listView.ItemsSource = data.ToList();
        });

    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Right now, my code just runs and doesn't display anything. The debugger also shows nothing parsed from the XML. I think I've got my Descendents / Elements mixed up, I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: I think you need to specify the namespace URL also when loading the elements, since a namespace is defined in the document for the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem -among other problems- that causing your code to display nothing, was that your XML has *default namespace*, and all descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace implicitly, unless otherwise specified. You need to use fully-qualified name to address element in namespace, f.e by using combination of `XNamespace` + element's local name .

*I personally* prefer query syntax for this specific task, try this way :

```
XNamespace d = "urn:connexionz-co-nz:jp";
var data = from route in loadedData.Descendants(d+"Route")
           from destination in route.Elements(d+"Destination")
           from trip in destination.Elements(d+"Trip")
           let routeNo = (string)route.Attribute(d+"RouteNo") ?? "test"
           let currentDestination = (string)destination.Attribute(d+"Name") ?? "test"
           select new Trip
           {
               RouteNo = routeNo,
               Destination = currentDestination,
               Eta = (string)trip.Attribute("ETA") ?? "5"
           };
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yeGk7s)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks! Yes, my major issue was the namespace. *wrecks head*